# What is the maximum mss over ethernet.?

Tags: networking, tcp

im New to tcp/ip please help

is it possible to have mss grater than 1460 in ethernet media.in wireshark always i can see 1460 as the mss.

[image]

Comment: Search Jumbo frame.

Comment: The MSS is the MTU minus the IP header and TCP header sizes. For IPv4, that would be 1460. As @LukeLee points out, some system and some network devices can use jumbo frames. Unfortunately, jumbo frames are not part of any standard, so if you read the ethernet standards, you will see that they are disallowed by ethernet. That has not stopped some manufacturers from adding jumbo frame support, but different vendors have different ways of implementing jumbo frames, and the jumbo frame size can vary among vendors that do support them.